# Why is my is my state different when navigating to a route via Link vs pressing the back button?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a main Layout component, that is connected to the appPageData state, in my redux store. The default state looks like this:

```
const initialSate = {
  appPageData: null,
  fetching: false,
  fetched: false,
  error: null,
};
```

My Layout component looks like this:

```
import React, { Component, cloneElement, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

//Components
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import Header from '../components/Header';

//Actions
import { fetchPage } from '../actions/appPageActions';

class Layout extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    const {pathname, query} = this.props.location;
    this.props.fetchPage(pathname, query);    
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const {pathname, query} = this.props.location;
    const {pathname: nextPathname, query: nextQuery} = nextProps.location;
    if( pathname !== nextPathname || query !== nextQuery) {
      this.props.fetchPage(nextPathname, nextQuery);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { appPageData, location, fetched, error } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <Header json={header}/>
        <section class="container" id="content" role="main">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              {cloneElement(this.props.children, { appPageData: appPageData, fetched: fetched, error: error })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <Footer json={footer}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Connect the component to the Redux store:
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    appPageData: state.appPageData.appPageData,
    fetched: state.appPageData.fetched
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
                              fetchPage: fetchPage
                            }
                            , dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Layout);
```

I pass the **fetched** prop down to the child components, in order to either show a loading indicator, or to show the component. All of this works great, if In the menu I use react router **Links** to navigate, however, when I press the back button, the child components brake, **because even tho my appPageData state has been reset to initial state, my layout sees the property "fetched" as true.**

My appPageReducer looks like this:

```
const initialSate = {
  appPageData: null,
  fetching: false,
  fetched: false,
  error: null,
};

export default function reducer(state = initialSate, action) {
    const {type, payload} = action;
    switch (type) {
      case '@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE': {
        return initialSate;
      }
      case 'FETCH_PAGE': {
        return {...state, fetching: true, fetched: false};
      }
      case 'FETCH_PAGE_REJECTED': {
        return {...state, fetching: false, error: payload};
      }
      case 'FETCH_PAGE_FULFILLED': {
        return {
          ...state,
          appPageData: payload,
          fetching: false,
          fetched: true,
          error: null
        };
      }
    }
    return state;
}
```

EDIT: My app.js looks like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';

//Main store of the app
import store from './stores/store';

//Main layout component of the app
import Layout from './pages/Layout';
import Data from './pages/Data';
import Login from './pages/Auth/Login';

// Create an enhanced history that syncs navigation events with the store
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path={appIndexURL} component={Layout}>
        <Route path={'**/**/a/data/**'} component={Data}/>
        <Route path={'**/**/a/login'} component={Login}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
app);
```

As you can see I'm listening to '@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE' to reset the state. Inside the redux developer console I can see the state changes correctly. There is no difference in how the actions are dispached or the how the state is updated, whether you use the Link or back buttons. It's the same, however, my Layout component, does not see it the same way.

It is as thought, Layout is re-rendering as soon as Back is pressed, before the state is updated? Would there be any reason for this?

Comment: How are you hooking up the `history` to the Router? https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md

Comment: @RedMercury I've edited the post to include my app.js. I think everything is hooked up correctly.

Comment: Looks legit. I can't see the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my code is correct. After I updated react router everything worked as expected.